# Compress files with the output name same as Parent Folder with Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, bash

I've been searching the internet for a solution to this.  I would like to create an Automator workflow that will zip the selected files, name the zip the name of the Parent directory and save that zip in the current directory.

I can't seem to find a way to get the parent directory. I've kinda hit a wall here. Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

In Automator:

1. Add Get Selected Finder Items
2. Add Run Applescript

Inssert this code for the Applescript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
 set pathList to {}
 repeat with itemNum from 1 to count of input
 tell application "System Events"
 copy POSIX path of (container of (item itemNum of input)) to end of pathList
 end tell
 end repeat
 return pathList
end run
```

Output/Results:

```
2013-05-11 00:06:02 +0000: Get Selected Finder Items completed
2013-05-11 00:06:02 +0000: Conversion from Files/Folders to Files/Folders completed
2013-05-11 00:06:02 +0000: Run AppleScript completed
2013-05-11 00:06:02 +0000: Workflow completed

{"/Users/Desktop", "/Users/Desktop", "/Users/Desktop"}
```

Comment: Ok cool, I tried returning the first item in the last with `return first text item of pathList` and I'm getting a list back.  My path as well as `"/Library/NetBoot/NetbootSP0"`. How can I return just the path I want?  Also is there a way I can just return the last directory in that path?

Comment: @tastytoast - `return item 1 of input` to get the first item only instead of `return pathList`. It should be fairly obvious if you study the code sample I provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Create Archive action and rename the resulting archive:

[image]

```
d=${1%/*}
start="$d/${d##*/}"
name="$start.zip"
i=2
while [[ -e $name ]]; do
  name="$start $i.zip"
  let i++
done
mv "$1" "$name"
open -R "$name"
```

Or use a run shell shell script action like this:

```
for n in $(seq $(printf %s "$@" | tr -dc / | wc -c)); do
  uniq=$(printf %s\\n "$@" | cut -d / -f1-$n | uniq)
  [[ $uniq != *$'\n'* ]] && dir=$uniq || break
done

cd "${dir:-/}"
[[ $dir ]] && start=${dir##*/} || start=archive
name="$start.zip"

i=2
while [[ -e $name ]]; do
  name="$start $i.zip"
  let i++
done

zip -r "$name" -- "${@#$dir/}"
open -R "$name"
```

If some files have extended attributes or ACLs, zip removes them. Archive Utility and the Create Archive action store them in the AppleDouble format.